# No pagination (page number) in Magento template Ultiomo

Tags: magento

I use in my Magento project template Ultimo and on Category which are actually a menu and sub-category I have pagination (page number) but on CSM-Page all works just fine except I dont see page number (pagination) any help, any leed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call  `<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">`  on your layout xml page

, and  then call this  `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` on your cms page